# Erlang: How to get current file cursor position

Tags: file, erlang, position

In Erlang, the `file` module allows one to move the file cursor to a given position by `file:position/2`.
But after performing an operation such as `file:read_line/1`, the cursor now moves.

Is there any way to get its current location?

Sorry if this seems silly, I'm new to Erlang and I cannot seem to find any relevant function in the module documentation to perform this. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the current file position, call [`file:position/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#position-2) with the atom `cur` as the second argument.

Comment: I completely missed that in the docs. This will return {ok, NewPosition} where NewPosition is equal to the current position. Much appreciated.